# Why is integral of $(\tan x)^3$ not $((\sec x)^2)/2 - \ln(\sec x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Messing around with u substitution, I tried to integrate $\tan^3x$ as follows:

$$
\tan^2 x \tan x = (\sec^2 x - 1)\tan x \\
u = \sec x \\
du = \sec x \tan x dx \\
du = u \tan x dx \\
du/u = \tan x dx
$$

so, the integral would be:

$$
(u^2 - 1)/u \\
u(u - (1/u))/u \\
(u - (1/u)
$$

integrating i got:

$$
(u^2)/2 - \ln u
$$

which would be:

$$
(\sec^2 x)/2 - \ln(\sec x)
$$

Whats wrong with this?

Comment: [That's correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+tan^3%28x%29). Note that $$\ln{\sec{x}} = - \ln{\cos{x}}$$

Comment: But ((secx)^2)/2 - ln(secx) does not equal ((tanx)^2)/2 - ln(secx), which is the answer given in stewarts book.

Comment: $\sec^2{x}$ and $\tan^2{x}$ differ by a constant, so that just gets rolled into the $+C$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint $1+tan^2(x)=sec^2(x)$ so differentiation is same . integral differels by $1$ note we also use this for $tan^2(x)$